# makehuman skeletal animation export to three.js

Tags: three.js, blender

I try in Three.js to load skeletal animation (bhv) from blender (make human).

It is revision 77 last , make human last version 1.1.0 .

I try  older version of three.js (js format) exporter for blender

Nice work with file from three.js repo : marine_anims.js
not gui for me but clip goes play ...

About error : trackName at all

three.min.js:316 Uncaught Error: cannot parse trackName at all: .bones[spine-1].position

.bones[spine-1].position
Fixed :
 .bones[spine_1].position

(do it for all strings with - )

**Last version of my code is based on blendCharacter.js from three.js .**

Maybe blender export ( blender 2.77a ) is wrong!
- skinIndices and skinWeights are all zero [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...0]

- Also (json last ver exporter)
  in one of variant i gets success with skinIndices and skinWeights  but :

  {
          "rotq": [0,0,0,1],
          "parent": 7,
          "pos": [-2.0792,1.92099,7.0397],
          "name": "DEF_lolid.R"
      },

  {
          "rotq": [0,0,0,1],
          "parent": null,
          "pos": [0,0,-0],
          "name": "DEF_f_index.03.L"
      },{

parent : null ( 95% , 5% is correct )

I cant fix with hands it too complicated ...

(js format exporter)
three.min.js:306   can not bind to bones as node does not have a skeleton T…E.PropertyBinding {path: ".bones[hips].position", parsedPath: Object, node: 11, rootNode: 11}

Online demo : 
http://maximumroulette.com/stack_demos/blendAnimationThreeJs/

(forget files missing) Put this in console !

FONTANA____.blendMesh.mixer._actions[0].play()

**19 dec 2016 update** : I found easy way for importing animation with bhv .
Its collada format . I succes to implement one animation sequence. I will post about this after implementation more than one animation (in one export).

Answer (score 1):

Currently the most reliable ways to bring skeletal information into three.js from Blender are FBX and glTF.

- [FBXLoader example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fbx#webgl_loader_fbx)
- [GLTFLoader example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=gltf#webgl_loader_gltf), [Blender exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/), and a [tutorial on character animation with Mixamo](https://medium.com/@donmccurdy/creating-animated-gltf-characters-with-mixamo-and-blender-728dc120e678).

Comment: Nice , i will see !